# Hole in countertop too big for faucet

Tags: faucet, countertops

I took out an old insta-hot faucet in our kitchen countertop and the hole that had been drilled was too big in diameter for any newer water filter faucet.

The diameter of the hole is around 1.5" while the diameter of the faucet fixture cover is barely that large. Unfortunately the new faucet moves around a lot and we want to find something we can plug the hole with to create a more secure seal.

The surface material of the countertop is Corian.

I was thinking something like epoxy might work, but I also don't want to make this too permanent so I can't remove the water fixture if it breaks.

Any suggestions on epoxies or other materials I should look at to make the seal a bit tighter around our water faucet? Any tips?

We're talking about half an inch in diameter or so to fill.[image: Sink Faucet Picture]

Answer (score 2):

As the chrome cover seems to cover the hole then I would make a wood or plastic or metal collar that fits in the existing hole and has a suitable diameter hole for your new tap.

Make it sufficient thickness to suit.

If you still have an offcut of the worktop you could make it from that. Even consider gluing it into place but the next tap may need the larger hole...

Comment: If you know anyone with a 3D printer - this is what they are perfect for!

Comment: @SiHa I find my holesaw set to be cheaper...

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't suggesting a purchase.

Comment: Thank you! We likely will do something similar with a piece of rubber -- sand or carve it down to fit, then drill a hole through the middle. Lots of ways to solve this one for sure! Unfortunately the hole was drilled 10+ years ago, well before we moved in so we don't have the offcut.

Comment: I ended up ordering two different rubber gaskets from Home Depot, one ended up being close enough for me to shave and sand it down. I spent a good 30-60 minutes carving the rubber gasket to the right size on the outside edge AND the inside edge. After many attempts it fit well around the neck of the faucet under the silver cap. It's a pretty snug fit but could come out in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a new washer that goes on the bottom of the counter top. It would be large enough to cover the existing hole in the counter top and have a hole in the middle that is the correct size for the new faucet.

This may be a tough ask, so you may need to *make* one out of 3/8 or 1/2" plywood.

- Using a hole saw, cut a circle out of the piece of plywood large enough to fit securely over the hole in the counter top.
- Using a smaller diameter saw, just large enough for the new faucet to fit through, use the same pilot hole in your disk to guide the saw to make the new faucet's hole.
- Since this will be used in a damp location, you may want to use pressure treated lumber, or, you may want to seal the whole thing in epoxy to protect it from any potential leaks.

If, of course, you have metal working tools (or know someone who does), you could make this out of a sheet of *much* thinner metal. You could probably use a hole-saw designed for cutting metal to do this, but I'd suggest that you use a drill press as you'll need to cut slowly and keep it lubricated to avoid overheating the bit & the metal.

Place your new faucet through the hole in the counter top. Place the washer over the stem from below. Screw on the mounting nut that came with the faucet.

You may also want to cut a "washer" to use as a filler donut to go *inside* the hole in the counter top to prevent the faucet from wobbling. Repeat the steps above, but make the outer diameter *just* large enough to be a snug fit into the counter top hole. A little bit of silicone caulk between the donut and the counter top should prevent wiggle and water ingress, yet still be removable if a larger faucet stem needs to be installed in the future.

The drawback to this method is that the stem of the new faucet may not be long enough to go through the counter top *and* the new washer (especially one made of wood).

Answer (score 0):

An option that uses either epoxy or pretty much any quick-set material which hardens in place is to line both the hole in the countertop and the barrel of the new faucet with plastic wrap.  Then center the faucet barrel in place and tape or otherwise seal the bottom of the hole.

Pour in the liquid material and wait until hardened.

Granted this is close to something [Professor Branestawm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Branestawm)  would do :-)

Comment: Not a bad idea. Extreme care would need to be taken to ensure one doesn't epoxy the faucet into the countertop thus rendering it unable to be removed in the future!

Comment: I wonder if I can use some beeswax candle material to make a plug the same diameter as the faucet -- then melt it after. Thank you both for your suggestions! I have limited tools so I may try this option first.